# how should i do, to get output file name in order?

Tags: file-format

when render animation with frame **end 20** and **step 4**,
will get  5 output file name like this:

```
0001.png,0005.png,0009.png,0013.png,0017.png
```

it possible to get output name like this ?.

```
0001.png,0002.png,0003.png,0004.png,0005.png
```

Comment: Thinking ahead, this doesn't make much sense since you would loose the original filenames, which is a pain to re-construct or figure out what frames you have rendered, later in the process. I'd suggest copy the folder and use something like [mucommander](https://www.mucommander.com/) to rename the copies to be on the save side.

Answer (score 2):

**After render.**

If you have set the render file path such that it **only contains the rendered images with that file extension**, can run this script, from within the blender text editor,  after rendering.

```
import bpy
from pathlib import Path

op = 'RENAME' # to rename
#op = 'CLEAN' # to remove

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
render = scene.render
ext = render.file_extension


rfp = Path(render.filepath)
fldr = rfp if rfp.is_dir() else rfp.parent

for f in sorted(fldr.glob(f"*{ext}")):
    if op == 'CLEAN':
        f.unlink()
    elif op == 'RENAME':
        print(f.name, end=" -> ")
        num = int(f.stem) // scene.frame_step + 1
        f2 = fldr / f"{num : 05d}{ext}"
        if not f2.exists():
            f.rename(f2)
        print(f2.name)
```

Output after rename.

```
0001.png ->  0001.png
0005.png ->  0002.png
0009.png ->  0003.png
0013.png ->  0004.png
0017.png ->  0005.png
```